# How to listen to child events created programatically in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've two components a child and a parent.

I'm instantiating the child in the parent manually & mounting it manually.

This is because My child component is rendereless and it doesn't have a tag like `<app-child></app-child>` which I can use it to instantiate in the template.

**NOTE THAT HERE I'M NOT BINDING TO PROPS AND LISTENING TO EVENTS IN A REGULAR MANNER AS IN THE VUE - TEMPLATE BINDING AND LISTNENING**

Here I'm not dealing anything with the template.

SO I will have to pass props and listen to events as given below.

But the issue is that even though I'm emitting event from child and listening it inside the parent. I'm not seeing any sign of it.

thought I'm listening to child event in parent as given below... I'm not getting any response from the event.

this is the parent

```
import { Child } from "./components/child";
import store from "@/store";

export default {
  name: "parent",
  components: {},
  props: [],
  data() {
    return {
      child: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {},
  created() {
    this.child = new Child({
      store,
      parent: this,
      propsData: {
        item: 'one' /// I'm being able to pass props and receive them in the child component
      },
    }).$mount();
    this.child.$on("hello", (e) => console.log(e, "yes")); // this is not working.
  },
  mounted() {
  },
  methods: {},
};
```

this is the child emitting event... 'hello'

```
import Vue from "vue";

const CHILD = {
  name: "child",
  components: {},
  props: ["item"],
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  render() {
    return null;
  },
  computed: {},
  created() {
    
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$emit('hello', 'parent')  /// this is child emitting event. this should be caught by the parent..
  },
  methods: {},
};

export const Child = Vue.extend(CHILD);
```

**How can I solve this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event is firing as it should. The issue is that you're missing the event since you're registering your listener *after* the event already fired.

Try changing your parent component as follows:

```
  created() {
    this.child = new Child({
      store,
      parent: this,
      propsData: {
        item: 'one' /// I'm being able to pass props and receive them in the child component
      },
    })
    this.child.$on("hello", (e) => console.log(e, "yes")); // Set up listener before event will be fired
    this.child.$mount();
  }
```

Here's an example of it working: https://codepen.io/gurupras/pen/qBNWbag

Comment: What if I want to listen to events after mounting?? Will I be able to do that?

Comment: The only issue here is that you're listening to the events _after_ they were fired.
As long as you set up your event listeners _before_, Vue will trigger those events, and your callbacks will be invoked.

In other words, yes. If you wanted to add a method to the child component that was invoked at some point in the code, and this method fired an event, your parent would be able to listen to this just fine---as long as it sets up the event listener before.

Comment: How should I fire events from the child so that I can catch them from the parent??

Comment: I have updated the codepen with an example of this as well.

Comment: So I should put all my listeners ```child.$on()``` before ```child.$mount()``` .... right?? There is no other way right..? (like ... first mounting... then listening)

Comment: Is that also possible..?

Comment: It is not necessary that you need to put _all_ your `child.$on` calls before `child.$mount`. You only need to ensure that your `child.$on` call happens _before_ the child calls `$emit`. When I say _before_, I don't mean before in terms of lines of code. I mean in terms of sequence of events.

Comment: Oh, Okkk. got it!!